# Odoo multicolumn index

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10

I need to create a two-column index. I have declared:

```
field_A= fields.Float(string='A', index=True) 
field_B= fields.Float(string='B', index=True)
```

But that creates two independent indices. I would like to obtain a composite index. Any idea how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It has to be done directly in the database. Odoo only supports automatic index creation for single columns.

An example from [PostgreSQL 9.6 Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/indexes-multicolumn.html)

`CREATE INDEX test2_mm_idx ON test2 (major, minor);`

Edit: On [a talk which is documentated here](https://github.com/odoo/technical-training/tree/d70ed04761a0a6792f1f621810a6f10d1a9a3bbf#index-in-odoo) Odoo is recommending the use of the `init()` method of a model.

> You maybe need (in rare case, PostgreSQL is able to combine indices) to add custom type of index or index on more than one field at the same time -> Use the init method to declare them

```py
#Example on mail.message, index on two fields
@api.model_cr
def init(self):
    self._cr.execute("""
        SELECT indexname FROM pg_indexes 
        WHERE indexname = 'mail_message_model_res_id_idx'
    """)
    if not self._cr.fetchone():
        self._cr.execute("""
            CREATE INDEX mail_message_model_res_id_idx 
            ON mail_message (model, res_id)
        """)
```

Comment: It works! I used the init method to create de indexes. Thanks